# Using a tags with php for a blog if variable is empty

Tags: php

I'm building a small blog site using SQL/PHP and I have the basics working and I'm now trying to implement tags so users can refine the topics displayed.

The code I have so far is:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT tblblog.id,title,img,figcaption,body,date,tag_id
    FROM tblblog LEFT JOIN tblblogtags
    ON tblblog.id = tblblogtags.blog_id
    WHERE tblblogtags.tag_id = ?
    ORDER BY date DESC");

$stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['tag']);

if($stmt->execute()){
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    foreach($result as $item){
    
    echo ...;
  }
}
$stmt->close();
```

My problem is if the `$_GET['tag']` is empty it returns no entries because it is passing empty or null to the $stmt. Other than implementing a `if(!empty($_GET['tag'])){}else{}` loop with two different statements is there a better way implement like using a CASE after the WHERE or filtering the array instead?

Comment: FYI: [Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Comment: I say go for the `if-else`. That is the clearest, most explicit way to write it. Leaves no room for confusion.

Comment: Yes, what @El_Vanja said. Writing code that you will be able to easily understand a year from now, is more important than getting “fancy” with “tricks”. You are going to need _some_ form of conditional logic here, so might as well make it explicit. But if you still want something “hacky”, then you could go with something like `WHERE 1 = ? OR tblblogtags.tag_id = ?`. By passing `1` for the first placeholder, you can make the whole condition _always_ true, so you can pass whatever you like for the second one (i.e., a dummy value, if no `tag` parameter was passed). […]

Comment: […] And if you _do_ have a specific tag value to filter for, then you pass `0` for the first placeholder, making that part of the condition always false, so that the result will solely depend on the second part. That’s basically shifting the conditional part of the logic to a different place then, by deciding whether the first placeholder needs to be substituted for 1 or 0.